# issue when inserting variable value to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am currently trying to  insert a global variable to a table. The other values I pass are variables too but they get sent correctly.

Here is my query. my error handling does not capture anything

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO IPmanagement (userId, NameUsed, EmailUsed, IPStatus, Ip) VALUES ('" .$masterUserId . "', '" . $Entry['LeadName'] . "', '" . $Entry['LeadEmail'] . "', '0', '" . $ip . "')") or die(ErrorException("Function 6", "Error when processing the current lead. your data is unaffected and if the proccess continues please contact an Admin.", mysql_error(),$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], CurrentPath(), $masterUserId));
```

my variable that is global defined before the function is

```
 $masterUserId = "1";
```

I tried echoing the variable before it sends and it echos out correctly YET my table holds a value of 0.

here is a screenshot of how I have my table setup.

[image]

[Click for **Larger Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEKFg.png)

Any idea what is going on. I am rather stumped and tried writing this same code different ways and it still gives me same issue. Also $masterUserId will always be an int value

Edit: also would like to mention the variable is different .php that contains the varaiable and database login information. It is being included at the top. (don't know if that is relevant)

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*`. Replace them with `mysqli_*` or `PDO::`. Did you try to echo the `mysql_query()`? Do this. Replace `mysql_query("...");` with `die("...");` and put it in the phpMyAdmin and try executing.

Comment: I don't think this is a PHP error. It must be a logical error. Try echoing  $masterUserId just before executing the query !

Comment: @GauravSrivastava The OP said he did it. Please read the question again!

Comment: Hi @EmanuelPermane, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not inserting `IP STATUS`.Which is not null

[image: DATABASE SCHEMA]

\

You should either set this to `null` or enter some value to it.

If you are using query in a function than use like this

```
function (){
//than define 
 $globat $masterUserId;
// use the global defination 
// than use this variable with global value
}
```

Comment: Good call, I added it but it still shows userId as 0. I am editing the original post to reflect that

Comment: @EmanuelPermane may be `$masterUserId = 1;` can help you try this.

Comment: @EmanuelPermane are you using defining its global defination like `function (){ global $masteUserId; //than code... }`

Comment: No i was declaring it outside of any function and then that file was included into this one.

Comment: It gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  on line 166.

I put the golbat in the same function i'm importing correct?

Comment: Gives me similar issue even if I rename to global which i'm sure you intended

Comment: Can you show your query functiin? You shold try to 'echo $query' it will show what is the value  of that vriable?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mysql_*`. Replace them with `mysqli_*` or `PDO::`.

Did you try to `echo` the `mysql_query()`? Do this. Replace `mysql_query("...");` with `die("...");` and put it in the phpMyAdmin and try executing.

And in your table, I see that `IP Status` is a `NOT NULL`. So that might throw an exception. Use a `default` value in the table.

And yeah, what do you get the result as in `mysql_error()`?

Comment: It gives you an output on what query will be executed, so that you can see if that was the required query.

Answer (score 0):

Why ''' or "' in query?
I have cleaned up query with PHP function [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and using NULL for EntryID(Autoincrement)

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO IPmanagement (EntryID,userId, NameUsed, EmailUsed, IPStatus, Ip) VALUES (NULL,%s,%s,%s,'0',%s)",
$masterUserId , $Entry['LeadName'] , $Entry['LeadEmail'] , $ip ));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

You should also use MySQLi or PDO